# how do you validate characters AND words in regex?

Tags: php, regex

### The Context

I'm in need of a bit of code that takes a very simple math string and runs PHP's `eval()` function. For example ...

```
  $math = '25 * (233 - 1.5)';
  echo eval("return $math;"); // returns 5787.5
```

However `eval()` is quite dangerous in the wrong hands, so the variable must be scrubbed. For the above, for example, a simple preg_replace would be ...

```
  $math = '25 * (233 - 1.5)';
  $replace = '/[^0-9\(\)\.\,\+\-\*\/\s]/';
  $math = preg_replace($replace, '', $math);
  echo eval("return $math;"); // returns 5787.5
```

... which ensures `$math` only contains valid characters ... `.,+-*/`, spaces and numbers, and no malicious code.

### The Question

I want to allow a few very specific words (PHP math functions), such as `pow`, `pi`, `min`, `max`, etc.

What's the cleanest way to validate both characters and words in regex?

So if given this string ...

```
pow(25,2) / pi(); hack the pentagon;
```

... how would I remove everything that wasn't in the `$replace` regex, but preserve the words `pow` and `pi`?

Comment: I was thinking an `explode` and re-`implode` might do it, but it's not the most elegant solution :\

Comment: I wonder if it would actually be easier to write a reverse-Polish parser to do this, and thus avoid the perils of `eval` altogether.

Comment: After a quick trawl and a little Google-foo I found a couple of PHP calculators that might form the basis of what you want. Take a look at [this](https://github.com/Sjord/calculator/blob/master/calculator.php), for example.

Comment: Interesting ... but how would I run the `pow()` or `pi()` functions? EVAL is so very close, it just needs a bit of filtering. Also I'm reluctant to add that many lines of code for such a small feature lol

Comment: Redacting my last statement ... you lead me down the right track, as https://github.com/chriskonnertz/string-calc might be just what I need

Comment: Yep, that library works perfectly :) I really could delete this question now, but I'd love to know how to do this with regex, so I'll leave it up for a bit to learn from the masters :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using php, you can match those words that you don't want to remove and use a [(*SKIP)(*FAIL)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24534782/how-do-skip-or-f-work-on-regex) approach.

You can also shorten the character class by remove the backslashes, and if you use a different delimiter than `/` in php you also don't have to escape the `/`

As you are replacing the matched characters in the character class with an empty string, you can use a quantifier `+` to match 1 or more consecutive matches and do a single replacement.

```
\b(?:p(?:i|ow)|m(?:in|ax))\b(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|[^0-9().,+*/\s-]+
```

The pattern matches

- `\b(?:p(?:i|ow)|m(?:in|ax))\b` Match either `pi` `pow` `min` or `max`
- `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|` What is matches so far should not be part of the match result
- `[^0-9().,+*/\s-]+` Match 1+ times any char except the listed chars in the [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated)

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Ze4vxX/1)

If you don't want the spaces at the start and end, you could consider to trim `$math`

```
$math = 'pow(25,2) / pi(); hack the pentagon;';
$replace = '~\b(?:p(?:i|ow)|m(?:in|ax))\b(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|[^0-9().,+*/\s-]+~';
$math = preg_replace($replace, '', $math);
echo eval("return $math;"); // returns 198.94367886487
```

Comment: This is gold. I knew it was possible. Thank you!